# Getting Index out of range when populating a tableview with a local array from parse.com

Tags: arrays, swift, parse-platform, tableview

I am trying to query some results(particularly the tags of posts) from parse.com and then appending it to a local array(not all of the posts have tags so I am trying to sort through nil and non nil ones and appending them to the array) which is populating a uitableview, but I seem to be getting the "fatal error: Index out of range" error.

I have read from other posts that this may be either due to the array being empty OR a mismatch between the array index and data in the array. I am pretty sure the array is being populated and is not empty. **The error is arising when the data from the array is populating the tableview.**

**Declaration of array...**

```
    var tagArray = [String]()
```

**This is my code that is pulling tags of posts from parse.com and appending it to local array tagArray...**

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "ParseClass")
    query.findObjectsInBackground { (objects, error) in
        if error == nil {
            if let objects = objects {
                for object in objects {
                    //self.tagArray.add(object)
                    if object.object(forKey: "tag") != nil {
                        print("tag is not nil")
                    self.tagArray.append(object.object(forKey: "tag") as! String)
                        //print(object.object(forKey: "tag") as! String)
                    } else if object.object(forKey: "tag") == nil {
                        print("tag is nil")

                    }
                }

            }
            print("success")
        } else {
            print("There was an error")
        }
    }
```

**This is the code where I am taking the data from the local array and populating the tableview...**

```
    let tagObject = tagArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel.text = tagObject
```

Please let me know if you need more information. Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Can you also include your `numberOfRowsInSection` method?

Comment: I had realized that I did not have the numberOfRowsInSection... I added it and that fixed the problem. I am still relatively new to coding so I forgot that. Thank you.